# vcvarsall.bat not found error while installing pynotify module for python 3.4.2

Tags: python

I know there are many questions and solutions on this but they seem to either give link to Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 while I am using python 3.4.2 or give link to download compiled module, but after thorough search, I couldn't find a compiled module for pynotify.

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'notify.gc' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Can anyone help me out soon? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**fastest solution:**

If you have python 3.4.x, the solution is simply to install VC++ 2010 since it is used to compile itself into.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express

my python version is MSC v.1600 32 bit (intel)] on win32

worked fine on Windows8